# avrdude: error reading signature data for part "ATmega4809", rc=-67

Tags: avrdude, arduino-uno-wifi

After some months working with the **Arduino uno wifi rev2** board, suddenly I got the message below when uploading any program. Tested in Mac, windows and different cables ...

---

Arduino: 1.8.9 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Uno WiFi Rev2, ATMEGA328"

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/BTB/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:megaavr:uno2018:mode=on -ide-version=10809 -build-path /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_cache_611323 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.2.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.2.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino14 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino14 -verbose /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/01.Basics/Blink/Blink.ino
    /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/BTB/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:megaavr:uno2018:mode=on -ide-version=10809 -build-path /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_cache_611323 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.2.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.2.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino14 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino14 -verbose /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/01.Basics/Blink/Blink.ino
    Using board 'uno2018' from platform in folder: /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.6.24
    Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.6.24
    Detecting libraries used...
    /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega4809 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO_WIFI_REV2 -DARDUINO_ARCH_MEGAAVR -DUNO_WIFI_REV2_328MODE -I/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.6.24/cores/arduino/api/deprecated -I/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.6.24/cores/arduino -I/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.6.24/variants/uno2018 /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp -o /dev/null
    Generating function prototypes...
    /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega4809 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO_WIFI_REV2 -DARDUINO_ARCH_MEGAAVR -DUNO_WIFI_REV2_328MODE -I/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.6.24/cores/arduino/api/deprecated -I/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.6.24/cores/arduino -I/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.6.24/variants/uno2018 /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp -o /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
    /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11/ctags -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
    Compiling sketch...
    /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega4809 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO_WIFI_REV2 -DARDUINO_ARCH_MEGAAVR -DUNO_WIFI_REV2_328MODE -I/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.6.24/cores/arduino/api/deprecated -I/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.6.24/cores/arduino -I/Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.6.24/variants/uno2018 /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp -o /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp.o
    Compiling libraries...
    Compiling core...
    Using previously compiled file: /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/core/variant.c.o
    Using precompiled core: /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_cache_611323/core/core_arduino_megaavr_uno2018_mode_on_e6754daa561557e34a3c7d8252f5bac7.a
    Linking everything together...
    /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega4809 -o /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/Blink.ino.elf /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp.o /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/core/variant.c.o /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/../arduino_cache_611323/core/core_arduino_megaavr_uno2018_mode_on_e6754daa561557e34a3c7d8252f5bac7.a -L/var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686 -lm
    /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/Blink.ino.elf /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/Blink.ino.eep
    /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/Blink.ino.elf /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/Blink.ino.hex
    /Users/BTB/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-size -A /var/folders/rq/05j9qrjj4s16s_pb24j6qzg00000gn/T/arduino_build_514686/Blink.ino.elf
    Sketch uses 1534 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 49152 bytes.
    Global variables use 22 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 6122 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 6144 bytes.

    avrdude: bad response to enter progmode command: 0xa0
    avr_read(): error reading address 0x0000
        read operation failed for memory "signature"
    avrdude: error reading signature data for part "ATmega4809", rc=-67
    avrdude: error reading signature data, rc=-67
    avrdude: error reading signature data, rc=-67
```

**Update**

Just tried with a 2nd Arduino UNO wifi rev-2 that was working this morning. Now I get the same error message and did not modified any line of code.

This is the sequence of how things happened:

1. tested it in Genuino linux this morning. Worked!
2. tested it in Genuino Mac this afternoon. Worked!
3. tested it in Genuino linux this afternoon. Did not work
4. tested it in Genuino Mac this afternoon. Did not work

I cannot upload any program

Please let me know if I could help testing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been solved in Arduino version 1.8.1

Go to Genuino> Tools> Board "Arduino Uno Wifi Rev2"> Boards Manager
 ... and update to 1.8.1 (or latest)

Read [here to find more details](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-megaavr/issues/33)